# When do rabbits need a dry and insulated place to sit?

Tags: health, safety, rabbits, containment, temperature

My female rabbit likes to sit on the grass in my garden. In summer, this seems normal to me, but in the colder seasons, I am worried about her health.

For example today it is a cloudy, foggy, and rainy day (the third in a row) with 7 degrees Celsius (44.6 Fahrenheit). The grass, logically, is wet.

When do rabbits need insulation from the ground?

My rabbits could choose between a hut to sit on top, a tub with wood pellets and straw standing on the ground in their enclosure, and a hut/stable with air+tub (includes wood pellets+straw) between them and the ground.

Comment: My female rabbit likes to snuggle in tunnels with both ends open. Maybe provide your rabbit with some soft tunnels?